# Huggingface AlBert tokenizer NoneType error with Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I simply tried the sample code from hugging face website: https://huggingface.co/albert-base-v2

```
from transformers import AlbertTokenizer, AlbertModel
tokenizer = AlbertTokenizer.from_pretrained('albert-base-v2')
text = "Replace me by any text you'd like."
encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')
```

then I got the following error at the `tokenizer` step:
`encoded_input = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt')`

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

I tried the same code on my local machine, it worked no problem. The problem seems within Colab. However, I do need help to run this model on colab GPU.

My python version on colab is `Python 3.6.9`.

Comment: Can you please add the versions of the transformers library you are using (i.e. `transformers.__version__`)?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found the answer. After install, import the `AlbertTokenizer` and `Tokenizer=...`, I received an error asking me to install `SentencePiece` package. However, after I install this package and run `tokenizer` again, I started receiving the error above.
So I open a brand new colab session, and install everything including the `SentencePiece` before creating `tokenizer`, and this time it worked. The `Nonetype` error simply means it doesn't know what is `albert-base-v2`. However if you install the packages in right order colab will recognize better the relationship between `AlbertTokenizer` and `SentencePiece`.
In short for this to work in colab

0. Open a new Colab session
1. Install `Transformers` and `SentencePiece`
2. import `AlbertTokenizer`
3. create `tokenizer`.

Comment: Thanks! This helped. Sometimes it's the good old "did you tried to turn it on and off again?"

Answer (score 11):

MeiNan Zhu's answer is correct.

Installing or importing SentencePiece before transformers works.

```
pip install Sentencepiece
!pip install transformers

tokenizer = XLNetTokenizer.from_pretrained('xlnet-base-cased', do_lower_case=True)

type(tokenizer)
```

> transformers.models.xlnet.tokenization_xlnet.XLNetTokenizer

Answer (score 4):

I just tried restarting the kernel and run again after installing - `!pip install sentencepiece` - and it worked..

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed *transformers* and *sentencepiece* library and still face NoneType error, **restart your colab runtime** by pressing shortcut key **CTRL+M .**

> (note the dot in shortcuts key)

or use **runtime menu** and rerun all imports.

**Note**: don't rerun the library installation cells (cells that contain pip install xxx)

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem, just restarting the Jupyter Notebook kernel after installing the sentencepiece library did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with `LlamaTokenizer.from_pretarined(MODEL_NAME)`.

With every `huggingface` tokenizer, you need the `sentencepiece` library to be installed. Here is my code:

```
!pip install -qqq transformers==4.28.1 --progress-bar off
!pip install -qqq bitsandbytes==0.38.1 --progress-bar off
!pip install -qqq accelerate==0.18.0 --progress-bar off
!pip install -qqq sentencepiece==0.1.99 --progress-bar off
```

Once you install the libraries, make sure you import them in order:

```
import textwrap
import torch
import sentencepiece
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer, GenerationConfig
```

And then make sure you restart your kernel, wherever you are writing code (Google-colab, VS Code,etc.). Otherwise, the installed libraries will not be recognized and you will get the weird `NoneType` error.